# Is $\mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n}\otimes\mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}^m} = \mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mathscr{B}$ denotes the Borel algebra.

Then,  $\mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n}\otimes\mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}^m} = \mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m}$ ?

I have proved that $\mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n}\otimes\mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}^m} \supset \mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m}$, but i'm not sure about the converse..

Comment: Yes, true for any separable space. Consult Folland's Real Analysis.

Comment: @Pedro Do you mean second countable? I think separable is too strong hypothesis

Comment: I mean separable, yes.

Answer (score 1):

A knonw result in measure theory is that $$\mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n} = \underbrace{\mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}}\otimes\ldots\otimes\mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}}}_{n \ times}$$ 
Now you use this to get $$\mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n}\otimes\mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}^m} = \underbrace{\mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}}\otimes\ldots\otimes\mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}}}_{n + m \ times} = \mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}^{n+m}}.$$

Now you just note that $\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^m = \mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ and you are done.

Comment: That is what the OP is trying to prove, really.

Comment: I see it differently. But ok.